# htaccess to redirect http:// and http://www to https:// that plays nice with subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, rackspace-cloud

I'm trying to redirect the following conditions:

```
http://mydomain.com
http://www.mydomain.com
```

to:

```
https://mydomain.com
```

But I don't want it to mess up anything with subdomains, so that someone who types:

http://m.mydomain.com

would not be redirected to https. My present htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've tried using some of the examples I've found here on stack overflow, such as this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But although it appears to have worked for that person, it resulted in a "redirect loop" for me. As an aside, after I get this working I need to add some redirects to handle subdomains, to invisibly (without changing the URL) redirect http://m.mydomain.com to http://mydomain.com/m for example. So whatever is done here shouldn't prevent that from happening.

If it helps, the site is hosted on Rackspace Cloud Sites

Anybody know how to do this?

Thanks!

**Edit**

I tried this:

```
#http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#subdomain 1
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/sub1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It seems to work for the most part, except that when I type in a subfolder it doesn't seem to work. For example, if I type this into the address bar:

```
mydomain.com/temp
```

It resolves to:

```
http://mydomain.com/temp/
```

**Edit 2**

Well I've made some progress. So far I have www redirecting to non-www, and subdomains working (though the address bar does change - I guess that's acceptable). What seems to mess it up is if I put any sort of forced-https in there. It seems to conflict with the www to non-www block. I can have one or the other. Is there a way to make those two parts work together?

Also, the WordPress site Address and WordPress Address are both set to `https://mydomain.com`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Redirect from www to non-www location
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect http to https
# THIS DOES NOT WORK - causes redirect loop
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 

# subdomain
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/sub1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/sub2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Conclusion**

For most web hosts, anubhava's solution would work just fine. However, the key here turned out to be Rackspace, I believe. They have their own preferred methods that I found by searching through their knowledge base. Here's the final htaccess file that works great. All www urls get sent to non-www urls, http gets sent to https, and subdomains redirect to their proper subdirectories, without messing up WordPress:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#subdomain 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/sub1/$1 [R=301,L]

#subdomain 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/sub2/$1 [R=301,L]

#get rid of www, works with rackspace cloud sites
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#force https, works with rackspace cloud sites
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Thanks so much for all your assistance with this.

Comment: jbalyo, as much as I appreciate you giving @anubhava credit, you should move your 'conclusion' to a separate answer and mark it as the answer.  I completely skipped over your question to read the solved answer, but reading all of the comments to that answer led me back up to here.

Comment: instant +1 if you do ;)

Comment: @ps2goat: Fair point, I updated the answer with final outcome below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#subdomain 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/sub1/$1 [R=301,L]

#subdomain 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/sub2/$1 [R=301,L]

#get rid of www, works with rackspace cloud sites
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#force https, works with rackspace cloud sites
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**PS: Note that the HTTPS server variable is not correctly implemented in a Rackspac Cloud Environment.** The correct variable to look at for HTTPS in Rackspace Cloud is `ENV:HTTPS`.

Comment: I tried this, thanks - but it created a redirect loop and crashes the site. I'm not sure why...

Comment: I just tried that, still get a redirect loop. And now I can't access /wp-admin/ anymore. Hmm...

Comment: Okay the wp-admin thing must have been some weird DNS issue - maybe the domain is still propagating (we switched it about 12 hours ago). Yes, typing `https://mydomain.com/` works, but I'm trying to make it so that typing `http://mydomain.com/` will forward to the `https://`

Comment: Same result, sorry. Redirect loop. I tried removing the subdomain part and still have the same result. I'm going to update my question with my latest htaccess file. I've made a little progress

Comment: I tried that again, a redirect loop. This is strange. I almost wonder if WordPress might be trying to forward things differently, causing the loops. I did set the WP URLs to `https://mydomain.com` as you suggested.

Comment: It is an series of 21 `GET mydomain.com 301 Moved Permanently`s The first of which is Remote Port 80 and all subsequent requests are 443. I guess the browser is correct that it's a loop. But why would it try to redirect to https when it's already on https?

Comment: Yes, with the 3 http to https lines commented out, it loads fine. There is only one `GET mydomain.com 200 OK` and then it proceeds to get the other elements on the page. Of course, they are all port 80

Comment: Is WordPress's normal behavior to forward everything to https if that is part of the wordpress URL? If so, maybe there is a conflict?

Comment: I figured it out! Rackspace has its own special methods. I only found it by searching through their help docs. Thanks so much for your help - your solution probably would work fine with any other host.

Comment: I thought the note about `ENV:HTTPS` was relevant at the top of the answer since the user was questioning about a rackspace cloud environment.  That's how/why I found this question!