# Htaccess for http:// on subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I currently have a website with a working .htaccess that forces https://www upon users visiting the site. I recently created a subdomain "demo.example.com", because both my main site "example.com" and "example.com/demo/" use different instances of the same CMS and cookies were being mixed up between the two installations (so using a subdomain would fix that).

I'm trying to have the following setup

```
http://example.com      => https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com  => https://www.example.com
http://demo.example.com => http://demo.example.com
```

But instead I get

```
http://example.com      => https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com  => https://www.example.com
http://demo.example.com => https://demo.example.com
```

Which slams my visitors to `demo.example.com` with an SSL warning since my certificate does not cover subdomains.

I've taken a look at other stackoverflow questions, and while this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988722/htaccess-to-redirect-http-and-http-www-to-https-that-plays-nice-with-sub) seemed to be promising, I *don't* want visitors on my subdomain to be redirected to it's subdirectory.

**Here's my relevant part of the .htaccess**

```
# BEGIN HTTPS Redirection Plugin
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS Redirection Plugin
```

Comment: You can move the subdomain to its own directory, rather than having it as a subdirectory of the main site, or you can modify your .htaccess to be limited to the main domain. Add your .htaccess to your question if that's what you want to change.

Comment: My apologies @JeremiahWinsley, I inteded to include it, but it slipped my mind. How would I go about putting this in its own directory? My main site is the root directory (public_html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root .htaccess of main domain you can have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Mind taking a look at my current .htaccess and incorporating this into it? (Updated original post with my htaccess)

Comment: Replace whole block between `# BEGIN` and `# END` by this suggested rule and keep this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: it doesn't appear to work when I go to my main site...
It works for my subdomain, but on my main domain, I simply get redirected to `http://www.`

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$ [NC]` will make it work only for `example.com` domain. You have to place it right in root .htaccess